# How do you use double in OpenCL on a MacPro?

Tags: opencl, gpu, osx-mavericks, double-precision

I have a Mac Pro (Late 2013) and I want to do some math in double using OpenCL.  When I was using Mavericks the `CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS` for my FirePro GPU only listed `cl_APPLE_fp64_basic_ops` so I couldn't use double math functions like `exp()`. I recently upgraded to Yosemite and now the proper `cl_khr_fp64` is in the list of extensions but I still can't use exp for double.  The error log shows that it's looking for an overloaded function and exp is available for float, float4, float8,... but not 64 bit.  I have included the command to turn on fp64:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
```

Does anyone know what's going on?  Why does the GPU say that `cl_khr_fp64` is available but then I can't use all of it.  I can `+-*/` in double, but I could also do that before with just `basic_ops`. Is Apple lying to me that they upgraded support of `fp64`?

Strangely, on my CPU OpenCL also says that `cl_khr_fp64` is also available but I can't use exp on the CPU either.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797959/1864294

Comment: @MichaelDorner , I tried this and it returns 63 for CL_DEVICE_DOUBLE_FP_CONFIG

I also found documentation from Apple that says the D700 supports double.

http://store.apple.com/us/buyFlowCTOLearnMore/ME253LL/A?group=graphics_z0pk

  Also, when I run this on my CPU via OpenCL it doesn't work either.  The CPU also returns 63 for CL_DEVICE_DOUBLE_FP_CONFIG

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCL kernel error on Mac OSx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791113/opencl-kernel-error-on-mac-osx)

Answer (score -1):

In OpenCL C, you should call them doubles not cl_khr_fp64s
e.g.
   `double  pie      = M_PI;

double2 two_pies = (double2){M_PI}; // or {M_PI,M_PI};`