# Opencl Code working on Mac Pro but not on Macbook Air. (clBuildProgram -11)

Tags: c++, opencl, build-error

I have a project written in OpenCL C++ wrapper. I have the complete project on Mac Pro (Late 2013 - Processor: 3GHz Core Intel Xeon E5 - Graphics: AMD Firepro D700 6144 MB). But when I moved it to my Macbook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013 - Processor: 1.3 GHz Intel Core i5 - Graphics: ntel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB) its not working. It gives me this error:

```
Exception
ERROR: clBuildProgram(-11)
```

This error is mostly related to syntax errors in the kernel.cl file. But since my project works perfectly on the Mac Pro, I don't see why there should be a syntax error just by moving it to Macbook Air.

Anyways, my best guess is that this error has something to do with the drivers or some missing installation or something like that. Can anybody help please?

**EDIT:**

So after some research, I found out that the error is basically with the double identifiers in the kernel. `__global double*` is not working. What is the solution for this? Why doesn't my OpenCL support double?

Comment: post code that reproduces the error, please:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just found out that the double identifier is giving the error. I edited my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797959/493106

Comment: basically consumer GPUs don't do double because it's really slow and not necessary for most graphics work.

Comment: So assuming that mine doesn't support double precision either, can I use float?

Comment: Almost certainly.   The "pro" level ati (fire pro) and nvidia (quadro) cards will support double, pretty much nothing else will (with the exception of the original nvidia titan card)